# How do i achieve this kind of styling in my post for my wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, styles

Here is the [link for the image](http://s255.photobucket.com/user/testament1234/media/post_zps0c881b88.gif.html?sort=3&o=0)

Basically i want the share buttons and read more button to be place at the very bottom of the div. Just like "Sample Post 14". The only reason i managed to achieved that is because of the excerpt or dummy text.  Is there anyway to accomplish that kind of styling. I'm using skeleton framework hence the class twelve columns or sixteen columns and etc

Here is my code:

### Index.html

```
   <div class="sixteen columns outer_box">
       <div class="inner_box articles">


           <!--TITLE OF THE POST -->
           <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>



           <ul class="data">
             <li><?php the_author_posts_link() ?> /</li>
             <li><?php the_category(', ') ?> /</li>
             <li><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> /</li>
             <li><?php comments_number() ?></li>
           </ul>

           <hr>

           <!--FIXED SIZE THUMBNAIL -->

           <div class="align_thumbnail_right">
               <div class="thumbnail"> 

               <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); echo '<img src="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" width="250px" height="150px" >';  } ?>
               </div>
           </div>


           <div class="content">
              <!--TEXT -->
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>


             <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><span>Read More</span></a>
           </div>

       </div>
   </div>

   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

### Style.css

```
.outer_box{border:1px solid #9f9191; margin:0px 0px 20px 0px}
.inner_box{margin:20px}
.articles h3 a{font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size:25px; color:black; text-decoration:none}
ul.data li, ul.data a{display:inline; font: normal normal bold 13px 'PT Sans', sans-serif; color:#565E66; text-decoration:none}
.content a{text-decoration:none; color:black; float:right; display:inline; font-weight:bold}
.content p{line-height:20px; margin-bottom:20px}


 /*POST THUMBNAIL */
.align_thumbnail_right{float:right; margin:0px 0px 20px 20px; background-color:#E8ECEF;}
.thumbnail{margin:5px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I got what you're asking here. I've used your code and tried to figure out your problem by editing the CSS - seems there are some styles that aren't included here, so I added it myself.

### style.css

```
.outer_box {border:1px solid #9f9191;margin:0 0 20px 0px}
.inner_box {margin:10px;overflow:auto;}
.articles h3 a {font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;font-size:25px;color:black;text-decoration:none}
h3.post-title {margin:0}
ul.data {margin:0;padding:0}
ul.data li, ul.data a {display:inline;font:normal normal bold 13px 'PT Sans', sans-serif;color:#565E66;text-decoration:none}
.content a {text-decoration:none;color:black;float:right;display:inline;font-weight:bold}
.content p {line-height:1.5;margin:0 270px 20px 0;height:120px;}

 /*POST THUMBNAIL */
.align_thumbnail_right {float:right;margin:5px 0 10px 20px;background-color:#E8ECEF;}
.thumbnail {margin:5px;}
```

I assumed the main issue from your previous code was the `inner_box`. Since you're using the `float` for the thumbnail, make sure the `inner_box` uses `overflow: auto` to cover the thumbnail inside the box. Then, for the paragraph you may add the specific `height` to maintain the share button and link aligned at the bottom.

Just a hint, for any `0` value in CSS, you don't have to add the `px` after it.

OK, hope this will help you.

Comment: Hmmm let try adding your code. I just hope it destroy the structure since the website is also responsive

Comment: destroy?! what do you mean by that?

Comment: sorry typo error i meant doesn't destroy haha. anyway your method works. I didn't know it was that simple just by adding height into it. Here is the screenshot http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/correct_zps904d47f1.png

Sorry if the image is a bit small. But you can clearly recognize the read more button just by the bold text. Oh by the way the site is responsive. I'll need to do a few more test. Maybe i'll add a character or word limit to excerpt

Comment: Ow, OK.. noted! *lol* I thought so. Great to know it helped you there.. well, good luck there!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an approach: [Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/8mzsh/)

HTML:

```
<div class="sixteen columns outer_box">
   <div class="inner_box articles">


       <!--TITLE OF THE POST -->
       <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">THE TITLE</a></h3>



       <ul class="data">
         <li>Autor post link /</li>
         <li>Category /</li>
         <li>Time /</li>
         <li>32</li>
       </ul>

       <hr>

       <!--FIXED SIZE THUMBNAIL -->

       <div class="align_thumbnail_right">
           <div class="thumbnail"> 

               <img src="" width="250px" height="150px" />
           </div>
       </div>


       <div class="content">
          <!--TEXT -->
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
       </div>

        <div id="buttonsPanel">
            <div id="sharePanel">
                <div id="facebook" class="shareButton">
                    <!--Code of Facebook Button -->
                </div>
                <div id="twitter" class="shareButton">
                    <!--Code of Twitter Button -->
                </div>
                <div id="google" class="shareButton">
                    <!--Code of Google plus Button -->
                </div>
                <div id="links">
                <a id="readLink" href="">
                    <span>Read More</span>
                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
#sharePanel {
   width: 100%;
}

#buttonsPanel {
   margin-top: 10px;

}

.shareButton {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#facebook {
    background: blue;
}

#twitter {
    background: #58FAF4;
}

#google {
    background: red;
}

#links {
    width: 120px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Let me try yours. The share buttons is actually a plugin.